# Why is priority of round brackets ignored

Tags: c++, operators, post-increment

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    std::cout << (x++) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the x++ to be equivalent to ++x as the expression is enclosed by round brackets. And accordingly expect 11 to be printed, but the output is 10. Why?

**EDIT:** I understand that pre and post increment work differently, what I don't understand is that why bracket priority is ignored i.e if I say x = (a +b) * c, I expect a and b to be added first and then multiplied with c, instead of b *c and then addition with a

Comment: *I expect the x++ to be equivalent to ++x as the expression is enclosed by round brackets.* What gives you such a strange idea? Pre and post-increment is not a matter of priority.

Comment: You might have learned PEMDAS in school as "do the thing in parentheses *first*", but it's only taught like that because mathematical expressions are side-effect-free. It's really about argument grouping, and in programming, where execution order actually matters, our PEMDAS equivalents explicitly have nothing to do with execution order.

Comment: The post-increment gets executet at the end of the statement (after ;), not regarding the brackets in the calculation.

Comment: @Wernerson: That's not guaranteed either.